# CRM 2011 - Custom query for subform based on value entered in field on mainform

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

How can I filter a subform based on a value selected in a field on the main form. The mainform is a registration for an certain education. When the user selects the education, for which he wants to make a new registration, the subform must show all the sessions planned for this education.

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe filtering is supported out of the box by microsoft.  The subgrids are pretty limited.

This [article](http://mscrmking.blogspot.com/2011/06/crm-2011-how-to-filter-add-existing.html) might help.  The author has a method to build custom views with filters, simliar to the method of filtering lookups through script.  It is an unsupported hack, but may be able to be adapted to your situation.

Another option off the top of my head would be to build a silverlight list-application or custom IFrame which would filter the list based on the selected option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'll take a look at the article and check your answer if it worked for me.

Comment: ok, i took a while before i checked your answer, but something came in between. The article is really intresting!